# Derivative of function $f(x,y)=xy $

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Let $f:\mathbb R^2\to \mathbb R$, Which is the derivative of function $f(x,y)=xy ?$

Comment: Derivative with respect to what??

Comment: @AnneliseToft There are different notions of derivatives when considering multi-variable functions. A common one is that of the gradient vector field which is $\nabla f(x,y) = (\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}, \frac{\partial f}{\partial y})$.

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen hmm I don't know, that's why I'm confused, because if it were respect to x, it would be y.

Comment: maybe you mean 'differential' if so 

then $df = < \nabla f(x,y) | (dx,dy)>  $

Comment: @JohnJack I guess that's what I need to calculate, because the problem just says 'compute the derivative'

Comment: The actual derivative at a point $x_0 \in\mathbb R^2$ is a linear map $Df(x_0): \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$ such that $$\lim_{x\to x_0} \frac{f(x) - f(x_0) - Df(x_0)\cdot (x-x_0)}{\|  x - x_0 \|} = 0.$$ In this case, we can take $Df(x_0)$ to be the gradient of $f$ wherever both $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$,$\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$ exist and are continuous. However, all partial derivatives can exist (and not necessarily be continuous) at a point, and the derivative can still fail to exist. However, for your purpose, it almost certainly means the gradient.

Comment: @User8128 and if the problem also says, find the derivative using the definition, I would have to use the limit that you wrote?

Comment: @AnneliseToft Yeah exactly as User8128 said. So if they were asking if the function was differentiable then the limit definition as he gave it, but if they are asking for the derivative then $\nabla f$ as I defined it is probably what they want. See the answer below he does the one partial derivative of $\nabla f$ for you. The other one is done in exactly the same way.

Comment: Oh ok, thanks @JohnJack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition,
$$
{\partial f \over \partial x} = \lim_{h \rightarrow 0} {f(x + h, y) - f(x, y) \over h} = \lim_{h \rightarrow 0} { (x + h) y - xy \over h} = \lim_{h \rightarrow 0} { hy \over h} = \mbox{(take the limit yourself.)}
$$

Similarly for ${\partial f \over \partial y}$.